# Any drawback of building website based on JSON API for Data Access Layer

Tags: json, database, api, data-access-layer

For instance, in ecommerce websites, we generally have two interfaces. One with which customer interacts and places orders and one with which company employees interact to manage orders and customers etc.

If we divide this website into two different websites. That means, two different projects all together, not dependent on each other. Only thing common between both websites will be the database. Both websites will be using the same database. Then what would be a good option for making **Data Access Layer**

1. Each website have its own Database access code and entities.
2. Link both website with a centralized layer - which exposes Read/Write to database using API based on JSON

In my opinion, second option would be better. As it cancels out dependency of database, any changes made in database need not to be made at two places. And many other benefits.

But my only concern is, how much it could hamper performance of overall system? Because in that case we are serializing and de-serializing objects and also making use of HTTP connections.

Could someone please throw some light over what would be benefits and drawbacks of API backed Data Access Layer in comparison to having own Database access code.

Answer (score 2):

People disagree about the best architecture for this sort of thing, but one common and popular architectural guideline suggest that you avoid integrating two products at the database layer at all costs. It is simpler to have two separate apps and databases which can change independently of each other, and if you need to reference data from one in the other you should have some sort of event pipeline between the two configured on the esb.

And, you should probably have more than two back end databases anyway -- unless you have an incredibly simple system with only the two classes of objects you mentioned, you'll probably find that you have more than two bounded domains.

Also, if your performance requirements increase then you'll probably want to look at splitting the read and write sides of your services and databases, connecting the two sides through an eventing system of some sort, (maybe event-sourcing).

Before you decide what to do you should read [Implementing Domain Driven Design by Vaughn Vernon](http://smile.amazon.com/Implementing-Domain-Driven-Design-Vaughn-Vernon/dp/0321834577/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1423780330&sr=1-2&keywords=domain%20driven%20design). And, the paper on  [CQRS by Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html). And the paper on [event sourcing, also from Dr Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html). For extra points you should also read [Fowler on Microservices architecture](http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html).

Finally, on JSON -- and I'm a big fan -- but you should only use it at the repository interface if you're either using javascript on the back end (which is a great idea if you're using [io.js](https://iojs.org) and [Koa](http://koajs.com/)) and the front end ([backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) & [marionette](http://marionettejs.com/), please), or if you're using a data-source that natively emits json. If you have to parse it then it's only going to slow you down so use some format native to the data-source and its consumers, that way you'll be as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1):

An API centric approach makes more sense as the data is standardised and gives you more flexibility by being usable in any language for one or multiple interfaces.

Performance wise this would greatly depend on the quality and implementation of the technology stack behind the API. You could also look at caching certain data on the frontend to improve page load time.

The guys over at [moltin](https://moltin.com) have already built a platform like this and I've had great success using it. There's already a backend dashboard and the response times are pretty fast too!